# Problem that get border line land 's positions from estate land

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There are a lot of values with "x, y" form in one array variable include all string item.

```
landArray = ["-4,2", "-3,2", "-2,2", "-1,2", "-1,1", "-1,0", "1,0", "0,0", "2,0", "3,0", "4,0", "4,-1", "4,-2", "4,-3", "4,-4", "-4,1", "-4,-1", "-4,0", "-4,-2", "-4,-3", "-4,-4", "-2,-4", "-3,-4", "-1,-4", "0,-4", "1,-4", "2,-4", "3,-4", "-3,1", "-2,1", "-2,0", "-3,0", "-3,-1", "-2,-1", "0,-1", "-1,-1", "1,-1", "3,-1", "2,-1", "3,-2", "3,-3", "2,-2", "2,-3", "1,-3", "1,-2", "0,-2", "0,-3", "-1,-3", "-1,-2", "-2,-2", "-3,-2", "-3,-3", "-2,-3"]
```

So I want to know border lines x, y values from this string array.

more detail is like this.
One land contain a lot of parcel land. For example one parcel land is like "2,-2". We already know about x and y positions of parcels that contains estate.
In this problem , we have to get borderline land's x and y positions from parcels of estate.
In image, each square is parcel.
I want to get square's x,y value in border line parcel , red line

[This image is estate land. red line is border line land.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxcJq.png)